# Render the content of a TemplateField dynamically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to know if there is a way of dynamically render the content of a template field from a GridView.

This is how the grid looks and what I want, is to somehow get the rendered string of the label in the code behind.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="simpleGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="false">           
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Templated Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="firstLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance,
Kali.

Comment: Are you saying you want the HTML of the Label control?

Comment: I'm asking if that is what you want to do, or if I was misunderstanding the question.  So that is what you want to do, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes ... i'd like to get the HTML of the rendered Label from inside the TemplateField.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way to get the content of a control is to use the RenderControl method, via something like:

```
StringWriter strings = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(strings);

Label label = //find the reference to the label
label.RenderControl(html);
```

This should push the control's markup into the html writer and easily extracted through the string writer.  That's one way.  Otherwise, no direct way to access its HTML except in client-side javascript.

HTH.